# on Safari , why drawing SVG circle is much faster than drawing Canvas circle?

Tags: canvas, svg, safari

I am drawing 550k circles on Safari(8.0.2)/chrome(39.0.2171.95).

Safari circle: SVG 3.5s   vs Canvas               6.8s

Chrome circle: SVG 15s vs Canvas 4.7s

Surprisingly, drawing SVG circles is actually much faster than drawing Canvas circles on Safari.
Do you know what may cause this?

BTW, here are the data I have for line and square

Safari line: SVG 6s vs Canvas 4s

Chrome line: SVG 8s vs Canvas 2.6s

Safari square: SVG 4.5s vs Canvas 0.6s

Chrome square: SVG 7.2s vs Canvas             1.36s

Comment: maybe it would help to see the code.

Comment: You're highly unlikely to be measuring what you think your're measuring as rendering is mostly asynchronous on UAs.